# What's the difference between Normals and Face orientation?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, texture-painting, normals

I'm following this really good tutorial, about Texture Painting, from CG Boost (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmbAs9jE1vI). 
At some point the the paint doesn't work because of flipped faces I realised that the paint doesnt work on some faces.
On a comment of this video on youtube, someone stated that recalculate the normals. If you did so the paint actually worked. But it brought a question:

On this image
[image]

I see that the red faces shows that the mesh is turned inside out, but this blue line show that the normals are facing out. 
Whats is the diference between face orientation an normals, and how can I make then to point to the same side ?

Comment: I think what's disturbing is that you see a normal pointing out a red face. But this is not the normal of this face. This is the normal of the face which is on the back pointing through the mesh.

Answer (score 3):

The normals come out of the blue faces:

[image]

But if two blue faces are facing and close to each other, showing red faces to the outside, you may have the impression that normals come out from the red faces. Simply because normal indicators (blue segments) go through the mesh:

Here on left something close to what you show in your question and on right the back face is shifted so that we can see the normals doesn't come from the center of the red face anymore:

[image]