# obvious seam artifact in mirror modifier with subsurf modifier

Tags: modifiers, mirror, subdivision-surface, artifacts, mirror-modifier

Okay i understand this is a common problem, and the common solution is setting the subsurf after the mirror in the modifier stack as shown here: [Subsurf and mirror modifier creating a split in mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh)

However in my case, my subsurf is already applied after the mirror and i still have an obvious seam. Here is the problem and how i tried to rectify it(in vain):

[image]

How do i get rid of this artifact?

Comment: Check your Normals (Face Orientation) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169407/2214 or try increase Merge value in Mirror

Comment: Also make sure you don't have an internal face at the join.